# model of angular select not updating in controller

Tags: angularjs, select, ng-options

I am trying to get  $scope.selectedBranch in controller but it is not updated. If I use $scope.selectedBranch in HTML it is working fine.

```
<select ng-model="selectedBranch" ng-change="onBranchChange()"  ng-options="branch for  branch in data.branches"
```

> All

```
$scope.onBranchChange= function(){
    console.log($scope.selectedBranch)  
};


data = {"branches" : ["343dfds","dfdf43","sdfsd","sadser343"]}
```

Answer (score 0):

Prefix $scope with data.
It should be like following:

```
$scope.data = {"branches" : ["343dfds","dfdf43","sdfsd","sadser343"]}
```

Comment: Thanks amit....but its not the issue... I just forgot to add $scope before data here.... In actual code its $scope.data only.

Comment: Then the code is working fine in my machine. Can you create or plunkr or somehing like that?